# Как обновить laravel c 5.4 до 5.8?

Tags: laravel, composer

Подскажите как правильно обновить ларавел с 5.4 до 5.8
в композер поставил так

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.0",
        "buzz/laravel-google-captcha": "^2.1",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "2.9.1 as 1.26.3"
    },
```

но при composer update выдает

```
composer-php7.1 update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 1 update, 1 removal
  - Removing kylekatarnls/update-helper (1.2.0)
  - Updating nesbot/carbon (1.39.0 => 2.9.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2 (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)        Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

Comment: а почему не 6.0?

Comment: в доках НА КАЖДУЮ ВЕРСИЮ есть гайд обновления - https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/upgrade